# Sql server combine two tables and multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have two tables:

Table A:

```
EmloyeeName
John
Mike
Bruce
```

Table B:

```
Date
2018-10-25  
2018-10-26  
2018-10-27  
2018-10-28  
2018-10-29  
2018-10-30  
2018-10-31
```

I want to have:

```
EmployeeName   Date
John  2018-10-25  
John  2018-10-26  
John  2018-10-27  
John  2018-10-28  
John  2018-10-29  
John  2018-10-30  
John  2018-10-31  
Mike  2018-10-25  
Mike  2018-10-26  
Mike  2018-10-27  
Mike  2018-10-28  
Mike  2018-10-29  
Mike  2018-10-30  
Mike  2018-10-31 
...
```

Which query to use?

Answer (score 5):

You need `CROSS JOIN` :

```
SELECT a.name, b.date
FROM a CROSS JOIN
     b
ORDER BY a.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select t1.EmloyeeName,t2.Date 
from TableA t1, TableB t2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by cross join as shown below

```
SELECT a.name, b.date
FROM TableA a CROSS JOIN
     TableB b
ORDER BY a.name;
```

Hope this will help you.